# Processing.js physics simulation

Tags: javascript, game, physics, processing.js

I've been fooling around in JavaScript again, and I've come up with this **simple** physics simulation. I think it has a pretty simple setup, here's *"psuedocode"* of sorts to explain it.

- Constructor `PhysicsEntity`

  - Private method `_calculateForces` - Calculates forces to be applied.
  - Private method `_applyForces` - Apply the calculated forces.
  - Private method `_renderEntity` - Render the `PhysicsEntity` at it's position.
  - Method `updateEntity` - Update the entity.

I think the interface is pretty clear, but if you have any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated.

```
/*
A simple physics object for managing
certain things such as forces acting
upon the object, and rendering.
*/
var PhysicsEntity = function(mass, entityWidth, entityHeight, accelerationVector, position, lifeTime)
{
    this.mass = mass;
    this.entityWidth = entityWidth;
    this.entityHeight = entityHeight;
    this.accelerationVector = accelerationVector;
    this.position = position;
    this.velocity = new PVector(0, 0);

    // Calculate the forces to be applied to the velocity
    this._calculateForces = function()
    {
        this.velocity.add(this.accelerationVector.x*this.mass, this.accelerationVector.y*this.mass);
    };

    // Apply velocity to the Entity's position
    this._applyForces = function()
    {
        this.position.add(this.velocity);
    };

    // Render the Entity at it's position
    this._renderEntity = function()
    {
        rect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.entityWidth, this.entityHeight);
    };

    // Update the entity
    this.updateEntity = function()
    {
        this._calculateForces();
        this._applyForces();
        this._renderEntity();
    };
};
```

Here's an example of how this can be used.

```
// Data for creating new PhysicsEntities and storing them
var DEFAULT_MASS = 1;
var DEFAULT_WIDTH = 10;
var DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 10;
var DEFAULT_ACCELERATION = new PVector(0, 0.2);
var DEFAULT_LIFETIME = 250;
var entityArray = [];


// Create a new PhysicsEntity at the mouse
var createEntity = function()
{
    entityArray.push(
        new PhysicsEntity(
            DEFAULT_MASS, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT, 
            DEFAULT_ACCELERATION, new PVector(mouseX, mouseY),
            DEFAULT_LIFETIME
        )
    );
};


// Update all entities
var updateEntities = function()
{
    for(var n = entityArray.length-1; n >= 0; n--)
    {
        var entity = entityArray[n];
        entity.updateEntity();
    }
};


// Main draw loop
draw = function() {
    background(255, 0, 0);
    createEntity();
    updateEntities();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Constructor(){
  this._isMyPrivates = function(){}
}
```

The usual problem with this "function inside this constructor to emulate private" approach is that every instance of the constructor will have *copies* of the functions. This will eat up your memory fast, especially that your object sounds like a base class for physics objects.

Try using prototypal inheritance instead.The methods are defined once, and shared rather than defined for each instance.

```
// Constructor
var PhysicsEntity = function(mass, entityWidth, entityHeight, accelerationVector, position, lifeTime){
    this.mass = mass;
    this.entityWidth = entityWidth;
    this.entityHeight = entityHeight;
    this.accelerationVector = accelerationVector;
    this.position = position;
    this.velocity = new PVector(0, 0);
};

// Prototype
PhysicsEntity.prototype._calculateForces = function(){}
PhysicsEntity.prototype._applyForces = function(){}
PhysicsEntity.prototype._renderEntity = function(){}
PhysicsEntity.prototype.updateEntity = function(){}

// This means that
// instance (where props live) -> prototype parent (where methods live)
//                                      A
// another instance (where props live) -' // literally pointing to the same object
```

And don't worry about "private". One can easily tamper the JS anyways, one way or another. You can prefix privates with underscores, as it's the usual convention.